# How to set a server-wide variable in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, variables

I have to maintain a variable in my Application.(cfm|cfc) to set the environment which the application currently runs under, the environment being (development|test|production).

I'd like to set an environment variable on the server itself, so that I can read its value in the Application.cfm.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easiest is to set a OS environment variable (at the system level, or for the user ColdFusion runs under), and restart the service. The variable is then available in the CGI scope:

```
<cfset EnvName = CGI.COLDFUSION_ENVIRONMENT>
<cfoutput>#EnvName#</cfoutput>
```

You could also use Java system properties. In your ColdFusion Administrator, go to "Server Settings/Java and JVM", and add something like this to the "JVM Arguments":

```
-Dcom.mycompany.environment=development
```

You can then ask for that value in ColdFusion:

```
<cfset System  = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.System")>
<cfset EnvName = System.getProperty("com.mycompany.environment")>
<cfoutput>#EnvName#</cfoutput>
```

You would have to restart the CF Service every time you make a change, but the value seems pretty static so this should not be a problem.

Comment: yay, that works. many thanks. btw, how do you guys do that kind of separation?

Comment: the separation of code chunks which should be executed only on dev/test/production boxes.

Comment: When editing your post, have a glance to the right (at the help box) and up (at the various editor buttons). ;-)

Comment: actually i was talking about the separation in your application.cfm and not in the posting ;)

Comment: Oh. Wood/trees, you know the story. :-D I think this is material for a separate question, not for an out-of-view discussion in some comments. I recommend you abstract the issue into a new question and see what people come up with. :)

Comment: I love the jvm approach - I'm currently sniffing details in the server scope, but that's much better - thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

Using apache you could. In the apache configuration (httpd.conf) or your virtualhost if you have the Env module loaded you can do this:

```
SetEnv APP_ENVIRONMENT DEVELOPMENT
```

Then from ColdFusion:

```
#cgi['APP_ENVIRONMENT']#
```

If you dump the CGI scope the value will not show, but, it will be there if you output it.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i don't run apache and don't seem to be able to find the setting in iis to do that kind of stuff :/

Comment: this post (from a quick google search) http://forums.iis.net/p/1146779/1858505.aspx suggests it's possible in iis7

Comment: +1 for the hint that it is not shown when dumping the CGI scope!

Comment: Beware that the SetEnv approach seems to open up a security hole if my tests are correct, at least on Coldfusion 8. You can use e.g. Modify Headers plugin in Firefox and send a header called APP_ENVIRONMENT with a new value and ColdFusion 8 will pick up the value sent from the browser, not the one set in vhost. According to the docs, Coldfusion creates it's CGI variable by combining values from the Server and the Request. I haven't got this confirmed, but it seems values in the request take precedence. I don't know if this is the case in newer versions of Coldfusion as well.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought on reading the question was to set a SERVER variable:

But then the problem is, where to set that?

In CF9 there'll be a onServerStart() method for this sort of thing.

Comment: but then you'd have to maintain that in every application you have, don't you? SETENV and the -D option are set on the *server itself*. no idea how i should have put it different :)

Comment: No, SERVER scoped vars are available to the whole of your ColdFusion server. You might be thinking of the APPLICATION scope.

Making it a CGI variable is handy as it'll work across application servers too.